# Internal Server Error when calling POST method

Tags: c#, api, http, console-application

I am trying to create a console application that is able to push things into a database by calling a certain API. I have control over neither the database or the API. The API is working fine as I already created tested the GET method, but I guess there is something wrong with my POST.

So first, I create the **Product** object containing the values that I want to send to the API.

```
Product product = new Product
{
     productId = "27795",
     amount = 1,
     customerid = 0,
     returnbasketid = true
};
```

And this is the method which is supposed to call the API's POST method.

```
static async Task CreateProductAsync(HttpClient cons, Product product)
    {
        using (cons)
        {
            HttpResponseMessage res = cons.PostAsJsonAsync("", product).Result;
            res.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
            Console.WriteLine(res.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result);
        }
    }
```

Upon running the code, line `HttpResponseMessage res = cons.PostAsJsonAsync("", product).Result;` has the following error:

> System.AggregateException: 'One or more errors occurred. (Response status code does not indicate success: 500 (Internal Server Error).)'
>
> HttpRequestException: Response status code does not indicate success: 500 (Internal Server Error).

I guess that the problem is how I send the values to the API and what the API expects. I have this data expected example:

```
    {
"":[{
 "productId":"27795",
 "amount":2,
 "customerid":0
},{
 "productId":"27796",
 "amount":1,
 "customerid":0
}],
 "returnbasketid":true
}
```

I already tested this using Postman and it is working fine, so the problem must be with my code.

https://pastebin.com/pZDehaaD This is a full example of my Program.cs. The API url has been removed, though.

**EDIT**: So this is the JSON that my console application is sending:

[image]

Whereas the JSON that works through Postman is this:

[image]

So the question is how should I write my code so the JSON that I am sending is properly configurated?

Comment: To be clear, you are passing a valid URL to `PostAsJsonAsync`, not an empty string, correct?

Comment: Most often this is error is because you have a malformed URL -- did you verify that url works in a browser?

Comment: That is correct. The URL is working well when I am using it in Postman or in the browser.

Comment: What are the inner exceptions wrapped bythe aggregate exception ?   I imagine that they will indicate your problem...

Comment: @Mark `HttpRequestException: Response status code does not indicate success: 500 (Internal Server Error).`

Comment: https://pastebin.com/pZDehaaD This is a full example of my Program.cs. The API url has been removed, though.

Comment: @Questieme I agree with your diagnosis.  May I suggest using Fiddler to compare your request with that of Postman ?

Comment: @Mark sure, I will look into it and return once I get more information.

Comment: @Mark there you go: https://imgur.com/pQV0hBy and https://i.imgur.com/4P1iByI.png. The first image is from the console app, the second is from Postman

Comment: @Questieme You need to send a wrapper object that contains an array of Products and a returnbasketid field, rather than just a single product.  Sorry, you had the correct structure in your initial question, but I thought that was the response

Comment: @Mark you got me totally confused at the wrapper part. Would you mind helping me out with a sample code on how that wrapper object looks like?

Comment: @Questieme  sure, I'll add an "answer" to make use of the formatting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're passing a Product to the API (that's the first Fiddler capture above).

But if we look at the required input (the second Fiddlel capture above), and also the "data expected example" (grey background), we see an object that contains an (unnamed) array of Products and field called "returnbasketid".

What we need to do if re-create this object.  We can call this class a "Wrapper", or "MyRequestObject" or any other name.  The name is not important.   I would try code of this form.

```
public class Wrapper
{

    [JsonProperty("")]  // rename json property to empty string - don't know if this will work
    public List<Product> Products { get; set; } = new List<Product>();

    public bool returnbasketid { get; set; }
}
```

You then pass an instance of this Wrapper, instead of a Product, to the  with cons.PostAsJsonAsync() call.

The problem with this is that our Wrapper's Product array has a name, and the server wants an array without a name.   I'm trying to rename the array above.  If that works great.  Otherwise I think you'll be obliged to create the json yourself (easy with Newtonsoft) and then post with HttpClient's PostAsync(Uri, HttpContent).